# Generating unique random numbers using follow logic. But looks like its failing

Tags: java, multithreading

What's the possibility of below code generating same last 7 digits when called successively from one thread?

```
try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
String temp = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());
return new BigInteger(temp).add(BigInteger.valueOf(new Long(activityIdCounter.incrementAndGet())));
```

`activityIdCounter` is `AtomicInteger` and above snippet is `static` `synchronized`.

I am asking this because I have found intermittently my test cases have failed due to existing id being reused. And this is a part of getting the unique ids.

Right now, I have changed to `System.nanoTime()` but I am not sure how

1. duplicate numbers may get generated, and
2. currently generated id matches a 6 days old id already present in DB.

Let me explain briefly how this `generateId()` method is called.

Tests classes call it twice sequentially for each call to DB for generating two different ids and both ids are persisted. Any other call or test method, will also do same. But for the operation to succeed in DB, this ids will be searched if they exist already in DB as `...where id1=:id1 and id2=:id2`.

Now here is my TestNG configuration:

`<test verbose="2" name="FullTestSuite" annotations="JDK" preserve-order="true" parallel="classes" thread-count="10">`

Edit: id creation logic

```
id1 = new BigInteger(<12-13 digits - constant>).add(<generated id>).toString();
id2 = "someString:" + id1 + ":" + generatedId; //call again for those 7 digits
```

Comment: This sounds overly complicated

Comment: You only use the last 7 digits of the generated BigInteger?

Comment: Much probable, I would think for e.g. `1498487760151` , `1498497760151` `System.currentTimeMillis` is not a good indicator for uid, it is used in generating unique ids, but it itself is not an unique id. You may try using [`java.util.UUID.randomUUID()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html#randomUUID())

Comment: Try using `ULID` - it is pseudo unique, meaning it gives you a very high probability for getting a unique value. It is composed of the current time and a random part. It is better than `UUID` mainly because it is faster and maintains order (more or less) because it is based on the current time. See: https://github.com/alizain/ulid

Comment: Why you are not using `java.security.SecureRandom` to generate random numbers?

Comment: @bowmore that 7 digits are added to a constant and converted to string.
added this to question.

Comment: Current id is based upon time. Means for each request, we are storing it in server and comparing later. And any new request is not expected to not match earlier. If it matches, we dont process it. So its risky.

Answer (score 1):

If you only use 7 digits you have 10 000 000 possible different values. Assuming you picked numbers completely random over that range, then after picking 3723 numbers, the odds of generating a duplicate are greater than 50%. And after 6785 picks, odds for generating a duplicate are over 90%.

Of course you don't pick them randomly, you try to make them increase. But if you only pick the last seven digits, then purely time based, you have an overflow after 10 000 000 milliseconds, or once every 2 hours, 46 minutes, and 40 seconds. And since you add an ever increasing number to the millis, that period will get shorter and shorter.

Also note that since you use `System.currentTimeMillis()`, you are exposed to changes in the system clock by other processes, most notably processes that do NTP sync. This means that two successive calls to `System.currentTimeMillis()` may see a lower value on the second call.

Conclusion : to safely generate unique ids, you'll have to use way more digits. In fact don't reinvent the wheel, use `UUID.randomUUID()`.